# Why does the same equation give different big-O values

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

In an example presented in a lecture slide, the big-o analysis confuses me.

It states: 2n^2 + 4n = O(n^2) AND 2n^2 + 4n = O(n^4)

Can someone explain how the same equation can produce different results? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `"="` does not mean its "is equal to", it means "is" in the sense of analysis of algorithms. The point of big-O is to satisfy this:

`f(x)` is `O(g(x))` iff `0<=|f(x)|<=c*g(x)` where `c` is positive number.

So, in your case  `2n^2 + 4n = O(n^2) AND 2n^2 + 4n = O(n^4)` is true. But, we always use the "best function" here to describe the algorithm, so we use `O(n^2)`.

From the other side, `f(x)` is `Ω(h(x))` iff `0<=c*h(x)<=|f(x)|`. Now,  if you have `h(x)=g(x)`, that means `f(x)` is `Θ(g(x))`